# Having issues with using "Bulk Decompress Files on Cloud Storage"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Trying to unzip multiple zipped folders in Google Bucket using "Bulk Decompress Files on Cloud Storage." Instead of unzipping the file's appropriate subfolders, it comes out as a single plaintext file. Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [Bulk Decompress Cloud Storage Files](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities#bulk-decompress-cloud-storage-files):

> The Bulk Decompress Cloud Storage Files template is intended for single compressed files and not compressed folders.

This means that if there are several files inside a compressed folder, those files won't be decompressed and those files won't appear in your bucket.